# add elements to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java

I want to add [1] [1,2] [1,2,3] etc to  List>
but it does not work if I

```
  List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  for(int i=1;i<n; i++){
      w.add(i);
      a.add(w);
  }
```

I want each element to not be affected by each other.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: you are defining `w` two times

Comment: insead of adding `w` to `a` , add a copy of `w` to `a`.

Comment: `List<List<Integer>>` won't work, and adding the same array to list n times is not likely what you want to do. Do you want maybe nested for loops and different arrays to be added to list?

Comment: Your code does not compile, you can't assign `new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()` to `List<List<Integer>> a`. Instead, use `List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`. And please, in the future, make sure that you only post code that you know to compile correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for :

```
List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); //Use Arraylist inside

for(int i=1;i<10; i++){
    w.add(i);
    a.add(new ArrayList(w));
}

System.out.println(w);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Why we cannot use `a.add(w)` directly instead of `a.add(new ArrayList(w))`

Comment: If you will add `a.add(w)` it will add reference to the list **w** inside all elements of list **a**, and since you are constantly changing the list **w**, by adding more numbers, all elements in **a** list will point to same **w**, hence will contain like this

`[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] .....]` instead of `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], ....[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1;i<10; i++){
    // your logic here make use of Arrays.asList()
    a.add(Arrays.asList(i, i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm assuming that the second list I named `a` instead of `w`. So the problem here is that, you should make a deep copy of a list that is added to list of lists. Otherwise you are using the same object. Simply add `a.add(new ArrayList(w))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, new List(w) does a clone?

Comment: Right. It creates a new list object containing the elements from original collection.